# d3 got slow all of a sudden

Tags: performance, d3.js, mouseclick-event

Unfortunately, by 'all of a sudden', I mean between versions 3.1.1.10 and 3.2.0.  I have a scatterplot with about 3000 points in it, and we are trying to make a mouse click based tooltip work since tooltips based on mouseover events don't really work for us.

So, while testing our initial attempt, we saw that it took a full 2 or 3 seconds before anything happened.  I thought that was a little odd.  I mean sure, we're doing a nearest-neighbor calculation, but it's only 3000 points, so what gives?  I profiled it and found that *once we got the event trigger*, our calculations were only taking about 22 msec, so that's good.  So what is causing d3 to take so much time in getting us active on mouse clicks?  I started dropping in different versions of d3 to see if it was the culprit and sure enough, things were slow until I got back to version 3.1.0.  That one have us the mouse event pretty much immediately and our tooltip popups were now working well.

Only problem is I can't use 3.1.10 because I need the zoom().center() functionality that was added more recently.

So any ideas?  Anybody know why the slowdown occurred there? Can it be patched?  Can someone suggest a clever workaround? I can't be the only one who has seen this problem.
I brought it up in the d3 forum, topic number qfz11UYgMC8

I understand why I cannot post codepen demos here without code, but the 2  demos I have demonstrate my point above by differing only in what version of d3 is included in them. I will include the code here if people really want to see it, but it's pretty much standard d3.js where I create my scatterplot from a json object, and it's thousands of lines of code.

And the problem is definitely based on the size of the scatterplot.  A small plot of a dozen or so points pops up the tooltip right away, and the one with 3000 points is slow (on all d3.js libraries 3.2 and later).

Edit: adding code snippets, and codepen links
The code itself is thousands of lines long because the data itself gets embedded in the html.  Here is what I hope is the relevant code...

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Rolling D3 speed test</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.2.0/d3.min.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="file://C:/d3.v3.5.16.min.js"></script> -->
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" class="init">

// variable init left out for brevity
...
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width",viewportWidth)
            .attr("height",viewportHeight)
            .call(zoom)
            .append("g")
    .attr("class", "main")
            .attr("transform","translate("+(left_shift)+","+(top_shift)+")");
...
//mouse click on svg (to display tooltip on nearest point)
d3.select('svg').on("click",  function() {
  var startTime = new Date();
  var coords = [0, 0];
  coords = d3.mouse(this);
  var isClicked = isPointClicked(point_clicked);
  if(!isClicked) clicked(coords[0], coords[1]);
  point_clicked = false;

  var finalEndTime = new Date();
  var finalTimeDiff = finalEndTime - startTime;
  console.log('all click actions completed in '+finalTimeDiff+' milliseconds.');
});
 //mouse-right click event to remove tooltip
  d3.select('body').on("contextmenu", function() {
  d3.event.preventDefault();
  var ele = d3.select('div.tooltip');
  //if(ele!=="undefined" && ele!==null)
ele.style("opacity",0);
});

...
// x and y axis rendering removed for brevity
...

//draw all data
//var radius = 2.5; // 2.5 normally, 8 is good for testing small sets
var side = 2;     // takes place of radius
// shiftrect needs to be half the square size to center square on data point
var shiftrect = 1;
for(var k=0;k<plot_data.series.length;++k) {
    if(plot_data.series[k].visible === true) {
        var y_list = plot_data.series[k].ydata;
        var x_list = plot_data.series[k].xdata;
        svg.selectAll("dot")
           .data(x_list)
           .enter().append("rect")
       .attr("id", function(d, i) { return "rect"+k+i;})
           .attr("x", function(d) {return x(parseFloat(d))-shiftrect;})
           .attr("y", function(d,i) {return y(parseFloat(y_list[i]))-shiftrect;})
           .attr("height", side)
           .attr("width", side)
           .attr("fill",function() { return color(k);})
           .attr("clip-path", "url(#plot-clip)");
    }
}
```

Codepen that is slow
http://codepen.io/pkrouse/details/ONwQmz/

Codepen that is fast.  Only diff is version of D3 used
http://codepen.io/pkrouse/details/JXBpKo/

Comment: You can include links to external libraries (like d3.js) in the Stack Snippet feature included in the editor. As far as thousands of lines of code go, that seems to fall under the standard practice of debugging in order to isolate the issue in an MCVE. If it *really* takes 1000 lines of code to produce an MCVE, that's not a problem.

Comment: Is this on codePen ? Can you show us working code ? Codepen fiddle plnkr ... ?

Comment: OK, managed to include codepen links, and added relevant code as well.

Comment: thatOneGuy and TylerH, do the codepen examples show the problem?  If not I can add points to the plots to (hopefully) make it really obvious.

Comment: did you find a solution to this problem? I am in a similar situation, I have 5000 points and I want to pan and zoom but it's really slow it takes a second or more when I do zoom or pan on my chart. but if I have a line chart with the same data then that is super smooth like it is supposed to be.