# I have a nice way to speed up scatter plots in d3 if someone can help me with panning

Tags: d3.js, svg, mouseevent

This is related a question I posted earlier

[d3 got slow all of a sudden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36946523/d3-got-slow-all-of-a-sudden)

In that question, I pointed out a slowdown in d3.js that happened a few versions back (3.2).  The slowdown is most noticeable in IE, but is definitely there in other browsers as well.  The problem comes up when clicking the mouse, and it takes a long time (2.5 seconds in IE) before the mouse event even gets to our code.  The problem is caused by the amount of data in the plot.  Simple scatterplots do not have this problem.

No answers were forthcoming on the topic, so I am solving the problem a different way.  I am using nested divs like this:

```
<div class = "plot_container" id = "thing_plot_container">
<div class = "ghost_container" id = "thing_ghost_container"></div>
</div>
```

And this set of styles:

```
div.plot_container {
    position: relative;
    margin:0px; padding:0px; /* insurance */
    border: none;
}
div.ghost_container {
    position: absolute;
    margin:0px; padding:0px; /* insurance */
    top: 0px;left: 0px;
    width:0px; height:0px; /* width and height are irrelevant */
    overflow: visible; /* insurance */
    border: none;
}
```

This lets me put my d3.js plot in the outer plot_container div and a separate div in ghost_container that I attach mouse events to.

Here is the rest of the relevant code. First the main d3 svg:

```
var div = d3.select("body").append("div")
            .attr("class","tooltip")
            .style("opacity",0);

var viewportWidth = window.innerWidth - 40;
var viewportHeight = window.innerHeight - 80;
var svg = d3.select("#thing_plot_container").append("svg")
            .attr("id", "mySVG")
            .attr("width",viewportWidth)
            .attr("height",viewportHeight)
            .call(zoom)
    .on("dblclick.zoom", null)
    //.on("mousewheel.zoom", zoomFun)//for FF
    .on("DOMMouseScroll.zoom", zoomFun)//for FF(1.7 or earlier)
    .on("wheel.zoom", zoomFun)
            .append("g")
    .attr("class", "main")
            .attr("transform","translate("+(left_shift)+","+(top_shift)+")");
```

And this is the ghost div overlaying the regular div:

```
//
// set up ghost/overlay svg element to handle mouse clicks
//
var use_overlay = true;
var catcherWidth = viewportWidth;
var catcherHeight = viewportHeight;
var svgns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
if (use_overlay == true){
  var mouse_div = document.getElementById('thing_ghost_container');
  var mouse_svg_container = document.createElementNS(svgns, "svg");
  console.log('replace these magic numbers with viewportWidth and height');
  mouse_svg_container.setAttribute("width",catcherWidth+"px"); // clips on chrome/ff if not done this way
  mouse_svg_container.setAttribute("height",catcherHeight+"px");
  mouse_div.appendChild(mouse_svg_container);
  var rect_mouse = document.createElementNS(svgns, "rect");
  rect_mouse.setAttribute("x",0);
  rect_mouse.setAttribute("y",0);
  rect_mouse.setAttribute("fill","blue");
  rect_mouse.setAttribute("fill-opacity",0.05); // set this to 0.0 when working
  rect_mouse.setAttribute("width", catcherWidth+"px");
  rect_mouse.setAttribute("height", catcherHeight+"px");
  rect_mouse.setAttribute("onclick", "ghost_click(evt)"); // this HAS to be evt to get all browsers cooperating
  // leaving these mouse down/mouseup events to the original svg does not work. The overaly svg kills it
  rect_mouse.setAttribute("onmousedown", "ghost_mousedown(evt)");
  rect_mouse.setAttribute("onmouseup", "ghost_mouseup(evt)");
  mouse_svg_container.appendChild(rect_mouse)
}
```

This works very well as far as it goes.  This completely sidesteps the slowdown issue with element-heavy plots like scatter plots.  The mouse click event *immediately* gets served this way.  The problem is that I cannot grab with the mouse and pan my chart!  I need help getting the mouse events passed into the d3 pan/zoom code.

Here is a fiddle showing what I have so far:
https://jsfiddle.net/pkrouse/5sbqchnn/

Comment: So, nobody knows how to pass mouse events on from the svg that captured the event on so that d3 can respond?

Comment: Did you fix your performance problems? Did you try tracing the problems using the various Performance tracers browsers have in their developer tools (F12)?